# How to implement wordwrap in java while reading data from an ods file?

Tags: java, apache

I am trying to read multiple line data entered in a cell(ods).But in java it reads only the first line. Rest of the lines are not read. I've put wordwrap automatically in ods .

Comment: can you post you code?

Comment: Explain with proper data and share you code if possible

Comment: I can't post the code but it's like in ods cell the value is xxxxxx all x's in a new line. So when I try to read the cell value using sheet.getCellAt(i).getValue.toString() it only reads x.